# Writing dynamic SQL safely, with an example function that estimates rows in any view

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, view

Last week I wrote myself a client side pivot table generator. Included on the screen is a list of tables and views. Along the way, I found it helpful to have an estimate of the number of rows in a selected table or view. It turns out to be easy to get an estimate of a table count, but I didn't know how to get an estimate of the rows in a view. Today, I was reading

[COUNT(*) MADE FAST](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/count-made-fast/)

Laurenz Albe's blog post ends with this tidy piece of clever:

```
CREATE FUNCTION row_estimator(query text) RETURNS bigint
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   plan jsonb;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) ' || query INTO plan;

   RETURN (plan->0->'Plan'->>'Plan Rows')::bigint;
END;$$;
```

That. Is. Nice. I realized that this would work as a view estimator, so I wrote up (read "hacked together") a function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS api.view_count_estimate (text, text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.view_count_estimate (
    schema_name text, 
    view_name text)
 RETURNS BIGINT 

AS $$

DECLARE
   plan jsonb;
   query text;
BEGIN

   EXECUTE 
   'select definition 
      from pg_views 
     where schemaname = $1 and
           viewname   = $2'

    USING schema_name,view_name
    INTO query;

   EXECUTE 
   'EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) ' || query 
   INTO plan;

   RETURN (plan->0->'Plan'->>'Plan Rows')::bigint;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ALTER FUNCTION api.view_count_estimate(text, text) OWNER TO user_change_structure;
```

This brings me to one of the areas I'm a bit nervous about in Postgres: Creating dynamic SQL safely. I'm not really clear about the magic regclass castings, or if I should be using something like quote_ident() above. Is the built SQL with the USING list safe? I don't see how it could be.

I'm using Postgres 11.4.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Laurenz said, your current code is perfectly safe, but given the amount of paranoia around SQL injection nowadays, it's worth elaborating.

Consider the naive version of your function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION api.view_count_estimate(schema_name text, view_name text) RETURNS BIGINT 
AS $$
DECLARE result BIGINT;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || schema_name || '.' || view_name INTO result;
  RETURN result;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is obviously wide open to SQL injection, but can be easily secured in a couple of ways. The most straightforward is to use `quote_ident()`:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || quote_ident(schema_name) || '.' || quote_ident(view_name)
INTO result;
```

This guarantees that the concatenated strings are syntactically valid [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), by double-quoting them if they contain any symbols, whitespace, or uppercase characters, so there is no risk of the user input being interpreted as an unwanted SQL expression or keyword (though it has the potential downside of making your function inputs case-sensitive).

A much more succinct alternative to `quote_ident()` is to use the equivalent [`%I` format specifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT):

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %I.%I', schema_name, view_name) INTO result;
```

There is also a `%L` specifier for embedding string literals, equivalent to the `quote_literal()` function.

An even nicer approach is to pass view references via a [`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION api.view_count_estimate(view_id regclass) RETURNS BIGINT 
AS $$
DECLARE result BIGINT;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || view_id::text INTO result;
  RETURN result;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The "magic" behind the `regclass` type is actually pretty straightforward; the value itself is just the integer primary key of the [`pg_class` table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html), and it behaves like an integer in most respects, but the [casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html) to and from string values will query `pg_class` to find the name of the table, following the same quoting rules as `quote_ident()` and respecting the current [schema search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).

In other words, you can call the function with

```
SELECT view_count_estimate('my_view')
```

or

```
SELECT view_count_estimate('"public"."my_view"')
```

or

```
SELECT view_count_estimate('public.My_View')
```

...and the `regclass` conversion will resolve the identifier just as it would in a query (while the `text` cast within the function will quote/qualify the identifier as needed).

But all of this is only necessary if you need to substitute an *identifier* into your query. If you just need to substitute *values* into a query (as is the case in your function) then a parameterised query (e.g. `EXECUTE ... USING`) is completely safe. Query parameterisation is not simple string substitution; it maintains a clear separation between code and data (in fact, the entire SQL statement is parsed, and all identifiers resolved, before the parameter values are even considered), so there is no possibility of SQL injection.

In fact, since *all* of the variables in this case are simple parameters, you don't need a dynamic query at all; your function can just run the query directly, without the `EXECUTE`:

```
SELECT definition 
FROM pg_views 
WHERE schemaname = schema_name
  AND viewname = view_name
INTO query;
```

Under the hood, PL/pgSQL will build exactly the same parameterised query (i.e. `...WHERE schemaname = $1 AND viewname = $2`) and bind the parameters to your function inputs. This approach has the added benefit of only [preparing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) the query the first time you call the function within a session, and just re-binding the parameter values on subsequent calls.

Actually, in this case you don't really need the query at all. The [`pg_get_viewdef()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) will return the view definition for a given `regclass`, so the whole thing can be reduced to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION api.view_count_estimate(view_id regclass) RETURNS bigint 
AS $$
DECLARE
   plan jsonb;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) ' || pg_get_viewdef(view_id) INTO plan;
   RETURN (plan->0->'Plan'->>'Plan Rows')::bigint;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Nick, I just saw you answer and it's great. I've been digging into the stuff for the past two days and writing it up for myself. Your explanations are super lucid and helpful. It's also fantastic that you made the query so much tidier and simpler. SO is proving very helpful to me as I give things a go, ask, and then can absorb (at least some of) the new information and ideas I get on the list.

I've been at Postgres for about 2 years...it's a _massive_ amount to take on. Even after decades working with databases. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your function is safe from SQL injection.

Comment: Laurenz, thanks for the answer, and for the blog post that I started from. I'm also curious about the merits of USING vs other approaches, but I think that's another question. I'm researching it first and will see how far I get. -- Thanks

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. Your version with `EXECUTE ... USING` is just as safe from SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, much appreciated.